# PL/SQL package - calling a procedure within a package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am a pl/sql beginner trying to understand how to call procedure within the same package. This is a sample package body with 2 procedures. First is for creating an employee and second is creating an employee card if the emp_id is not empty. Can you please advice me how to proceed in the if statement block down below?

Thanks a lot!

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY sample_package
IS
PROCEDURE create_employee(
    emp_id IN OUT VARCHAR2,
    emp_name IN VARCHAR2,
    emp_surname IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    schema.package.procedure(
        emp_id,
        emp_name,
        emp_surname
    );

    IF (emp_id != null) THEN
        --how do I call procedure create_id_card
    END IF;
END;

PROCEDURE create_id_card(
    card_id IN OUT VARCHAR2,
    card_name IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    schema.package.procedure(
        card_id,
        card_name
    );
END;
END sample_package;
```

Comment: In order to call `create_id_card` from `create_employee`, `create_id_card` must be declared in the package header or be placed before `create_employee` or forward-declared above `create_employee` with `PROCEDURE create_id_card(card_id IN OUT VARCHAR2, card_name IN VARCHAR2);`.

Comment: refer the comments from Belayer "As currently written however the create_id_card procedure will never be called. This is not because the calling syntax in incorrect - it is correct. It will never be called because "(emp_id != null)" will never return True. Any operation applied to a null always returns null. You need "(emp_id is not null)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find a way of passing variables card_id and card_name in the procedure create_employee like the below

```
  PROCEDURE create_employee(
 emp_id IN OUT VARCHAR2,
 emp_name IN VARCHAR2,
 emp_surname IN VARCHAR2)
 IS
 l_card_id VARCHAR2(100);
 l_card_name VARCHAR2(255);
 BEGIN
schema.package.procedure(
    emp_id,
    emp_name,
    emp_surname
);

l_card_name:=emp_name;

IF emp_id is not null THEN
    create_id_card(l_card_id, l_card_name);
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that:

```
IF (emp_id is not null) THEN
    --how do I call procedure create_id_card
    create_id_card(parameter1, parameter2);
END IF;
```

As both procedures are in the same package, you don't have to do *anything* (precede its name with package or owner names, if that's what you meant).

I don't know which parameters you're actually passing so I named them just `parameter_x`.

Comment: As currently written however the create_id_card procedure will never be called. This is **not** because the calling syntax in incorrect - it is correct. It will never be called because  "(emp_id != null)" will never return True. Any operation applied to a null always returns null. You need "(emp_id is not null)"

Comment: Ha! Exactly, @Belayer! Thank you. Didn't pay attention to that at all.